# Убрать стиль после выбора значения js

Tags: javascript, html, css

Подскажите пожалуйста, есть js скрипт который ищет по таблице значения и выводит их:

```
<script>
       $(document).ready( function() {
            $('#category').keyup(function(){
                if($(this).val().length > 0){
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "POST",
                        url:"/autocomplete/auto_cat.php?id=<?=$_GET['id']?>",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {'choose' : $(this).val()},
                        success: function(res){
                            console.log(res);
                            var content = '';
                            $.each(res, function(i, item){

                                content += "<div class='ott_g' data-id='"+res[i].id_c_p+"'>"+res[i].name_c_p+"</div>";
                                $("#pk").css({"margin-top": "29px", "background": "#fff", "position": "absolute", "margin-left": "138px", "width": "170px", "border": "2px dashed #e0e0e0", "text-align": "left", "padding": "5px", "font-size": "15px"});
                            });
                            $('.aut_cont').html('');
                            $('.aut_cont').append(content);
                        }

                    });
                }else{
                    $('.aut_cont').html('');
                }

            });

            $('body').on( 'click', '.ott_g', function(){

                var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
                $('.user_id').val(id);
                var txt = $(this).text();
                $('#category').val(txt);
                $('.aut_cont').html('');

            });


        } );
 </script>
```

Суть в том когда выводиться содержимое у нас применяется стиль:

```
$("#pk").css({"margin-top": "29px", "background": "#fff", "position": "absolute", "margin-left": "138px", "width": "170px", "border": "2px dashed #e0e0e0", "text-align": "left", "padding": "5px", "font-size": "15px"});
```

Как убрать этот стиль после того как мы выбрали значение? Сейчас вот так происходит:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

После выбора значения:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Лучше вынести стили в класс, потом класс добавлять или убирать.

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko Подскажите как добавлять, убирать классы?

Comment: С помощью методов `addClass` и `removeClass`.

Comment: @Stepan Kasyanenko вы можете помочь с кодом? Я в js новичек...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуй просто передать пустой обьект в метод css